# Codeigniter 1.7.2 and PHP 5.3.1, Data not passing to view from controller

Tags: codeigniter

I have an app using CI 1.7.2.
In controller i have `$data['title'] = 'Sample Title';`
In view

```
<?php echo $title; ?>
```

Should print it.

But not working.
I have another app with latest CI, in that passing like this works fine.
Anybody know reason for this strange issue?

Comment: how are you passing it to your view?

Comment: Just setting `$data['title']` won't magically make the view able to read it.  You need to pass the `$data` array: `$this->load->view('page', $data);`.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the data to view like,

```
$this->load->view('view_file', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to pass data to view use the library parser

class home extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'date'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');


    $this->load->library('parser');


}

public function index() {

    $this->sssssssss();
}

function sssssssss($data = '') {

    $header = $this->parser->parse('interface', array(), TRUE);

    $data['interface'] = $header;

    //bind all together and parse to template view
    $this->parser->parse('template_view', $data);
}
```

}